# Mapping Doctrine's one-to-one relation as primary key in XML

Tags: php, doctrine

Consider example entity:

```
class Entity
{
    /**
     * @Id
     * @OneToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\User")
     */
    public $user;
}
```

How to save this mapping in XML?

Comment: Hi @emix. Check https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/xml-mapping.html

Comment: Especially [this](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/xml-mapping.html#derived-entities-id-syntax). Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it:

```
<doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping"
                  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                  xsi:schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping
                   https://raw.github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/master/doctrine-mapping.xsd">
    <entity name="AppBundle\Entity\Entity">
        <id association-key="true" name="user" />
        <one-to-one field="user" target-entity="AppBundle\Entity\User" />
    </entity>
</doctrine-mapping>
```

The key part was the `association-key="true"` so Doctrine stops complaining about having the `user` property already.